# Do Python dict literals and dict(list of pairs) keep their key order?

Tags: python, dictionary, literals

Do dict *literals* keep the order of their keys, in Python 3.7+? For example, is it guaranteed that `{1: "one", 2: "two"}` will always have its keys ordered this way (1, then 2) when iterating over it? (There is a [thread in the Python mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151263.html) with a similar subject, but it goes in all directions and I couldn't find an answer.)

Similarly, is a dictionary like `dict([('sape', 4139), ('guido', 4127), ('jack', 4098)])` ordered like in the list?

The same question is true for [other naturally ordered constructions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), like dict comprehension and `dict(sape=4139, guido=4127, jack=4098)`.

PS: it is documented that [dictionaries preserve insertion order](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights). This question thus essentially asks: is it guaranteed that data is inserted *in the order of a dict literal*, *of the list* given to `dict()`, etc.

Comment: It depends on the order of insertion. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6.

Comment: You're reading a thread from before they made the final decision on dict order preservation. They're order-preserving now.

Comment: So the question is whether dict literals, etc. insert in the order of the source code, etc. One could guess that yes, but is it guaranteed by the language?

Comment: Insertion order preserved as cpython implementation detail https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation, as language invariant https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Comment: Oops, I missed the PS and thought you weren't aware they're insertion-ordered. Instead, does this answer your question? [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867861/4518341)

Comment: A comment to Martijn Pieters's answer points to a [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) that settles the case of the literal and of the comprehension: they are ordered as it appears. There is still the case of `dict([…])` and of `dict(x=…)`, but we're getting close! Don't hesitate to write an answer with this information!

Comment: @EricOLebigot: The `dict(x=` bit is insertion order preserving by the earlier, pre-guaranteed `dict` ordering guarantee for keyword arguments `dict`s; they're received in the same order they're named when passed (they made that guarantee earlier than for `dict`s in general, because those are *always* new `dict`s, and there are no compromises required to keep insertion ordering like there are with regular `dict`s that undergo deletion and reinsertion and the like).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: what "earlier ordering guarantee for keyword arguments" are you referring to?

Comment: @EricOLebigot: The results of PEP 520 and PEP 468, both included in [the 3.6 What's New docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-520-preserving-class-attribute-definition-order). 520 guaranteed the order of class attribute definitions, 468 preserved keyword argument order. Both were side-effects of the new compact `dict` implementation, but unlike the general order-preserving aspects of `dict`s, they were made part of the language spec, not just an implementation detail, in 3.6.

Comment: Useful to know! I added these points to wjandrea's answer, so as to give a full answer to the original question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, any method of constructing a dict preserves insertion order, in Python 3.7+.

---

For literal key-value pairs, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> If a comma-separated sequence of key/datum pairs is given, they are evaluated from left to right to define the entries of the dictionary

- See also: [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308/4518341) on [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1867861/4518341)

For comprehensions, from the [same source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays):

> When the comprehension is run, the resulting key and value elements are inserted in the new dictionary in the order they are produced.

Lastly, the [`dict` initializer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) works by iterating over its argument and keyword arguments, and inserting each in order, similar to this:

```
def __init__(self, mapping_or_iterable, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(mapping_or_iterable, "items"):  # It's a mapping
        for k, v in mapping_or_iterable.items():
            self[k] = v
    else:  # It's an iterable of key-value pairs
        for k, v in mapping_or_iterable:
            self[k] = v

    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        self[k] = v
```

[This is based on the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/dictobject.c#L3305), but glossing over a lot of unimportant details, e.g. that `dict_init` is just a wrapper on `dict_update_common`.]

This, combined with the fact that [keyword arguments pass a dictionary *in the same order* since Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-468-preserving-keyword-argument-order), makes `dict(x=…, y=…)` preserve the order of the variables.

Comment: Nitpick: It looks for the `keys` method to identify mappings, not `items`. It then uses `items`-like iteration for `dict` subclasses that haven't overridden `__iter__`; for everything else, it iterates the keys and looks up the values. Using `items` would make much more sense, but I suspect historical inertia keeps it using `keys`. None of this invalidates your answer, thus, mere nitpicking.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah, like I said, I'm glossing over a lot of unimportant details. That's good to know if you're implementing your own mapping-like class, but I just wanted to give a simple, high-level idea of how it works.